# Execute/Parse Shortcode in Native WordPress Custom Field Value Field

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I've spent some time searching for a solution but have not found 1 single example of how to do this.

I would like to place a shortcode in the value field of the Custom Field meta box in WordPress so it executes on the front end without hardcoding the shortcode into a template file.

[image]

Here's my standard code i'm using to hook in the output of the shortcode on the front end via my template:

```
$two = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'field_2_solid', true );
    if( ! empty( $two ) ) {
    echo '<div class="wrap">'. $two .'</div>';
}
```

I understand i can hard code it into the file but thats not flexible and not what i want to do.

Not sure it can be done.

Comment: it looks like the suggestion by @TheDeadMedic will solve this - a cool magnifying glass effect you got there ;-)

Comment: Yes @birgire Just worked out how to do that in preview > tools > Show magnifier.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/):

```
echo '<div class="wrap">'. do_shortcode( $two ) .'</div>';
```

Comment: In the Custom Field Value field ( Meta Box )?

Comment: No,the custom field value should remain the shortcode - it's only on the frontend you want to "execute" it, right?

Comment: Yes @TheDeadMedic +1 Works perfectly. thanks.